# pip install django mysqlclient 'path should be string, bytes, os.PathLike or integer, not NoneType' on windows

Tags: python, mysql, django, windows

I am new to Python and Django and want to install mysqlclient on windows. When I use the command `pip install django mysqlclient` in cmd it throws this error :

> File "d:\myprojects\python\mytestdjangoprj\myproject\lib\genericpath.py", line 30, in isfile
>           st = os.stat(path)
>       TypeError: stat: path should be string, bytes, os.PathLike or integer, not NoneType

Please help me.

Comment: Make sure you are using 64 bit Python. There are wheels for the latest mysqlclient 1.4.5, so `pip install mysqlclient` should work today as long as you are using 64 bit Python 3.6, 3.7 or 3.8.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As Alasdair said , using 64 bit solve problem.thanks Alasdair.